# Ping an IP, pop-up messages and save results to txt file - VBS

Tags: vbscript, ping, connectivity

I'm making a simple script that pings an address and save the results in a txt file.

The purpose is solely to make it convenient for the lay user that don't know how to:

1. open the "run" box;
2. open cmd;
3. ping an address;
4. copy results;
5. past to a txt file.

So far, I have made this .bat file, but I wanted it on vbs for more functionalities and better visual.

**.BAT APPROACH**

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOPSTART
time /T >> PingTest.txt
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 100 >> %userprofile%\Desktop\PingTest.txt
exit
GOTO LOOPSTART
```

**.VBS APPROACH**

```
Dim WshShell, i
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Popup "This program will run a connectivity test using PING", 5, "PING TEST!"

Dim strHost, strFile

strHost = "1.1.1.1"
strFile = "ping_test.txt"

PingCall strHost, strFile

Sub PingCall (strHost, outputfile)
    Dim Output, Shell, strCommand, ReturnCode

    Set Output = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(outputfile, 8, True)
    Set Shell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    strCommand = "ping -n 100 " & strHost
    While(True)
            WshShell.Popup "Please, wait while test is being executed...", 1, "Test Running"
        ReturnCode = Shell.Run(strCommand, 0, True)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Problems I'm having - with the VBS script -:

1. Save the ping result to the .txt file;
2. Show a message indicating the test is running. I want to either
   show how many packets are still to be sent or either to have a box
   opened while it doesn't finish ("Pls, wait. This will close once
   test has finished...");

That's it.

Am I complicating it too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,fso,TmpLogFile,Logfile,MyCmd,Webaddress,Param
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
TmpLogFile = "TmpFile.txt"
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "log"
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then fso.DeleteFile LogFile
webaddress = "www.stackoverflow.com"
Param = "-n 10"
MyCmd = "Title Ping to " & DblQuote(Webaddress) &_
" & Color 9B & Mode con cols=75 lines=3 & Echo Please wait a while the ping to " & DblQuote(Webaddress) & " is in progress ... & Time /T > "& TmpLogFile &_
" & Ping " & Param & " " & Webaddress & " >> "& TmpLogFile &_
" & cmd /U /C Type " & TmpLogFile & " > " & LogFile & " & Del " & TmpLogFile & "" 
ws.Popup "This program will run a connectivity test using PING",5,"PING TEST!",vbInformation
Call Run(MyCmd,1,True)
ws.run LogFile
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            'MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /c " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            'MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Your code is brilliant. It's exactly what I needed. It's the same thing I did, but with the plus that I would never do it as good as you. Thank you. By the way, can I add new lines to the message "Echoed" in "MyCmd" (cmd /c Title & Color & Mode & Echo). I tried & vbNewLine & with and without double quotes, but didn't work as it recognizes what comes after & as a new method/argument(?).

Answer (score 3):

You could put this line into a shortcut

```
cmd /c ( Ping 127.0.0.1 > testPing.txt ) & ( date /t >> testPing.txt )
```

You need to use `WshShell.exec` which returns

> The WshScriptExec object is returned by the Exec method of the WshShell object. The Exec method returns the WshScriptExec object either once the script or program has finished executing, or before the script or program begins executing.

(from help)

It gives you access to StdOut which is where the text is. Do a `ReadAll` on it.

However VBScript can do it's own pinging

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From win32_PingStatus where address='104.43.195.251'")
For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox "Status" & objItem.statuscode & " Time " & objItem.ResponseTime
Next
```

Use to do 100 times.

```
Do while Counter < 100
    Counter = Counter + 1 
    ...Ping code here ...
Loop
```

For help on what properties are available, in a command prompt

```
wmic PATH win32_PingStatus get /?
```

PingStatus doesn't have any methods, but if it did

```
wmic PATH win32_PingStatus call /?
```

You would need to put the script into an HTA (basically a web page named script.hta) and update the web page with a counter. You can steal code from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976290.aspx

Comment: Your answer is awesome. I could understand your idea and codes. Also you provided me with relevant resources. You gave me the direction. Thank you. The only problem here is me. My lack of knowledge would lead me to bang my head against the wall for too long. Giving information and guidance is good, but sometimes one doesn't need it or need a more straightforward approach: do this, this and this, this way, or the solution itself, like @Hackoo did. Thank you again.