# Average ping time using VBS

Tags: vbscript, ping

Sorry for reopening the question, but I need to calculate an average time of the response to the different servers and then find out which one is the fastest.

How can I do it? I'm really new to VBS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106383/ping-an-ip-pop-up-messages-and-save-results-to-txt-file-vbs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812916/how-to-get-average-reply-time-from-ping-command will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle the code Ansgar Wiechers gave you into a function:

```
Function AveragePing(p_sAddress)
    Dim objWMI
    Dim sQuery
    Dim sngResponseTime
    Dim iResponses
    Dim iCounter

    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

    sQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE address='" & p_sAddress & "'"

    sngResponseTime = 0
    iResponses = 0

    For iCounter = 1 To 2
        For Each pingStatus In objWMI.ExecQuery(sQuery)
            If pingStatus.StatusCode = 0 Then
                sngResponseTime = sngResponseTime + pingStatus.ResponseTime
                iResponses = iResponses + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If iResponses > 0 Then
        AveragePing = sngResponseTime / iResponses
    Else
        AveragePing = -1
    End If

End Function
```

Then you can create a list of servers and call this function to get the average times for each server:

```
Private Sub PingServers()
    Dim dicAddresses
    Dim sAddress
    Dim sngAverage
    Dim sngFastestTime
    Dim sFastestAddress

    Set dicAddresses = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dicAddresses.Add "72.30.35.9", "72.30.35.9"
    dicAddresses.Add "216.58.195.78", "216.58.195.78"

    sngFastestTime = 0

    For Each sAddress In dicAddresses
        sngAverage = AveragePing(sAddress)
        If sngAverage > 0 And (sngFastestTime = 0 Or (sngAverage < sngFastestTime)) Then
            sngFastestTime = sngAverage
            sFastestAddress = sAddress
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Fastest ping average was " & FormatNumber(sngFastestTime, 2) & " for " & sFastestAddress

End Sub
```